# Can't seem to figure out why looping through values in a request argument is splitting values

Tags: python, rest, flask, url-parameters

So I'm trying to loop through the values stored in an API parameter in Flask.
The issue I'm running into is that the values are getting printed as individual letters, instead of returning all the comma separated values. I was wondering if this was because I'm not supposed to be passing a list to my API url?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main.py

fruits= ["orange", "apple", "lemon"]

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit) ---> orange 
                      apple 
                      lemon
 

response = requests.get(f"127.0.0.1:9000/food?fruits={fruits}")

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

flask_api.py

from flask import Flask

@app.route('/food', methods=['GET'])
def food():

fruits = request.args.get("fruits")
print(fruits) ---> ["orange", "apple", "lemon"]

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit) ---> [o r a n g e a p p l e l e m o n]


return fruits

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=9000)
```

Edit:

This is my modified code after getting a response.

```
-----------------------
main.py

fruits= ["orange", "apple", "lemon"]

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit) ---> orange 
                      apple 
                      lemon
 

response = requests.get(f"127.0.0.1:9000/food", params={"fruits":fruits})

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

flask_api.py

from flask import Flask

@app.route('/food', methods=['GET'])
def food():

fruits = request.args.get("fruits")
print(fruits) ---> ["orange"]

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit) ---> [o r a n g e ]


return fruits

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=9000)
```

Comment: I think you're only getting one fruits parameter from your arguments. ("orange"). doing the loop thing for a single string prints every character, that is normal and expected behaviour. The problem is that you're not getting a list in the first place. If you wanna make this A LOT simpler, just use a POST request and put the list in the json body instead of using url arguments, that's far from ideal with a list.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 That's a good idea. Wasn't sure if making a POST request was ideal in this scenario. Going to try that. Thanks!

Comment: In your example, it doesn't really matter if you're using GET or POST. GET is generally used to "get" back data, for example from a database. But you're not doing that anyway, so... You're free to do whatever!

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting your parameters incorrectly. Here's what you did:

```py
from requests import Request

fruits = ['orange', 'lemon']

r = Request('GET',f'https://127.0.0.1:9000/food?fruits={fruits}')
u = r.prepare()
u.url

"https://127.0.0.1:9000/food?fruits=['orange',%20'lemon']"
```

Here's what should have been done:

```py
r = Request('GET','https://127.0.0.1:9000/food', params={'fruits': fruits})
u = r.prepare()
u.url

'https://127.0.0.1:9000/food?fruits=orange&fruits=lemon'
```

In the first example, all of the fruits are being sent as a string representation of a list, in the second they are sent as individual query parameters. As just a regular requests call:

```py
r = requests.get('https://127.0.0.1:9000/food', params={'fruits': fruits})
```

Comment: I tried to recreate your solution but having issues using that formatting for the get request. I'm using Python v.3, haven't seen the request format being used like that before. 

Granted I am a newbie developer. I did however try to pass the list as a parameter instead of appending it to the url as an API call and I'm still running into the same issue with the loop only returning the individual strings.

Comment: @SuperDummy No worries, the format is pretty much the same, `requests.get(url, params={'fruits': fruits})`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I ended up just sending the whole list via a POST request with help from @c8999c 3f964f64

Comment: Good deal, I'll leave this here just in case someone else finds it useful

Comment: I did have another follow up question tho. So I'm passing a list to the value in a key value pair and when I try to iterate through that list in the API, I'm getting the message "too many values to unpack" (eg `{"key": "[value, value value value]"}`  . I was wondering, how should I go about passing that information to Flask? Do I need to be converting it to a different variable type?

Comment: don't wrap the list as a string, pass it as a list